# Django logout function stopped working when creating userprofile function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am learning Django by creating a project.

The problem I am facing is that the user logout function stopped working after I created another function to view user profile in `view.py`.

Here are my codes in `view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from techuser.models import UserProfile
from techuser.forms import RegistrationForm


# Create your views here.
# Decorator
def login_executed(redirect_to):
"""This Decorator kicks authenticated user out of a view"""

def _method_wrapper(view_method):
    def _arguments_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(redirect_to)
        return view_method(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return _arguments_wrapper

return _method_wrapper


@login_executed('tech_blog:index')
def registrationview(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('tech_blog:index'))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration.html', context)


@login_executed('tech_blog:index')
def loginview(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        username, password = request.POST.get('username'), request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tech_blog:index'))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)

# Logout Function Which I am facing problem
@login_required
def logoutview(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tech_blog:index'))

# Logout function is working without this function. But I need this function for showing the user profile
@login_required
def ownprofile(request, user_name):
    user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)

    context = {
        'user': user,
    }
    return render(request, 'author-profile.html', context)
```

Here is the code from `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email Address",
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "example@email.com"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Last Name",
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Last Name"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "First Name"}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "username"}),
        }

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Here is the code from `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic', verbose_name="Profile Picture")
    about = models.TextField(verbose_name="About Yourself")
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}\'s About'
```

Here is the code from `url.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from techuser import views

app_name = "tech_user"

urlpatterns = [
    path('<user_name>/', views.ownprofile, name='ownprofile'),
    path('registration/', views.registrationview, name='registration'),
    path('login/', views.loginview, name='login'),
    path('logouturl/', views.logoutview, name='logouturl'),
]
```

And here is the URL call from the HTML file

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url "tech_user:ownprofile" user_name=user.username %}"><i class="fal fa-user-alt"></i> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url "tech_user:logouturl" %}"><i class="fal fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the error I am getting in **copy-paste view** in browser when calling the logout from HTML page (if only I have the `ownprofile` function in `views.py`):

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/logouturl/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'techblog',
 'techuser',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Bohubrihi\Courses\Bohubrihi Full Stack Web Development\05. Django Backend\Assignments\1\techbangla\techuser\views.py", line 189, in ownprofile
    user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /account/logouturl/
Exception Value: User matching query does not exist.
```

And this is one of the error I am getting in **interactive view** on the browser:
[image]

I have spent all days with this problem but still can not solve this. Can anyone help me solve this? Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the `Logout` function in your template a `form` that would be:

`template.html`

```
<form action="{% url 'tech_user:logouturl' %}" method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
```

Then in the function that defines the logout in your `views.py`

```
def logoutview(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tech_blog:index'))
```

Also in yoyr `urls.py` you can't just write `<user_name>`, when you use `<>` you need to specify the type you are passing through, so in this case:

```
from django.urls import path
from techuser import views

app_name = "tech_user"

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:user_name>/', views.ownprofile, name='ownprofile'),
    path('registration/', views.registrationview, name='registration'),
    path('login/', views.loginview, name='login'),
    path('logouturl/', views.logoutview, name='logouturl'),
]
```

I hope this changes solve your problem

Comment: I have followed your solution, But still has the same problem.